# Модальное представление и переход от него

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

если вызвал модальное представление, можно ли на правой кнопке NavigatorBar вызывать переход типа:

```
-(IBAction)aboutNav
{
    NSLog(@"aboutNav");
    AboutViewController *avc = [[AboutViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIBarButtonItem *aboutBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"about" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
    [[self navigationItem]setBackBarButtonItem:aboutBtn];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:avc animated:YES];
}
```

или модальное представление работает только для того чтобы показать и закрыться?
Чего спрашиваю)) NSLog(@"aboutNav"); выполняеться, а остальное нет))

Comment: Может. Ты просто не создал новый navigationController и пытаешься в "модальный" подставить переход.

Нужно создать новый NavigationaController пушить в него.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вызвал модальное представление внутри `UINavigationController` - можно делать все, что поддерживает `UINavigationController`, показывать `UINavigationBar` с `titleView` и `UIBarButtonItem`s, делать `pushViewController` и `popViewController`

в общем случае:

переход на модальный UINavigationController

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vcToGo];
[self presentViewController:navController completion:nil];
```

вот мы его показали, дальше внутри того, что показали (AboutViewController), во viewDidLoad где-нить, можно сделать типа

```
[self.navigationItem setLeftBatButtonItem:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(action)] animated:NO];
```

**что может быть не так в вашем случае**

проверь, нормально ли инициализируется `UIViewController`, не `nil` ли он

```
AboutViewController *avc = [[AboutViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController" bundle:nil];
```

происходит ли вобще `pushViewController`, появляется ли другой экран?

```
UIBarButtonItem *aboutBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"about" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
    [[self navigationItem]setBackBarButtonItem:aboutBtn];
```

совершенно бесполезно, если это первый экран в стеке вашего `UINavigationController`, у него нет backButton, да и сетить свою `backButton` обычно ни к чего не приводит и просто игнорируется, уж лучше тогда `setLeftBarButtonItem:` или `setLeftBarButtonItems:` к тому же, делать это сразу перед pushViewController бесполезно, поскольку после пуша на `UINavigationBar` действует уже `navigationItem` другого экрана, который только что запушили.
Казалось бы тогда нужно сделать `[avc.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"about" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil]];` и дело в шляпе, но проблема в том, что до того, как мы сделали `pushViewController:`, то есть до того, как `UIViewController` попал в `UINavigationController`, его `navigationItem = nil` и ничего туда засетить мы не можем.

Так что, **управлять содержимым navigationItem лучше в любом методе после viewDidLoad того UIViewController, кому эта navigationItem принадлежит. А презентовать модально лучше внутри UINavigationController если нужен UINavigationBar и/или навигация внутри.**

Answer (score 0):

К моему комментарию, наглядный пример.

*Может. Ты просто не создал новый navigationController и пытаешься в "модальный" подставить переход.
Нужно создать новый NavigationaController пушить в него.*

[image]

**К админам: Сорри, картинки только в ответе можно приложить, хотя я понимаю, что это не ответ.**

Comment: ок! попробую! но я не использую storyboard в своём проэкте((((

Comment: И? :) Так ты просто при viewDidLoad в модальном окне, создай UINavigationController и приаттач к этому окну. Тот же самый принцип, только программно.
Я наоборот не люблю програмно, много кода :)

Comment: модальный работает, а обычный нет.   
 ThirdViewController *tvc = [[ThirdViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tvc];

   // обычный [self.navigationController pushViewController:nav animated:YES];

   // модальный [self presentModalViewController:nav animated:YES];

Comment: [self.navigationController - мне кажется это не правильно, тут ты скорее всего обращаешься к тому, что привел тебя "сюда", а не к тому, что ты создал. Поставь "блокираторы" и посмотрю при ране, куда ссылается этот контролер.
Простое решение: tvc сделать strong переменной и self.tvc push...

Comment: один фиг ничего не получаеться, решил всё таки через модальное представление, а жаль(((

Comment: нельзя так просто взять и запушить UINavigationController в UINavigationController